# How to convert string ("20200127T135548") to date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have this string `20200127T135548` which needs to be converted to a `DATETIME` in SQL Server.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method would be replace the `'T'` with `' '` and then inject the needed `':'` characters:

```sql
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(datetime,STUFF(STUFF(REPLACE(V.YourValue,'T',' '),14,0,':'),12,0,':'))
FROM (VALUES('20200127T135548'))V(YourValue);
```